# Concatenating with <br/> in STUFF doesn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have the below code:

```
SELECT id, displayname = 
    STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + displayname
           FROM #t b 
           WHERE b.id = a.id 
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM #t a
GROUP BY id
```

instead of ', ' I would like to have `<br/>` tag in `STUFF`. is it possible to have HTML tag directly in `STUFF` command?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but you need to be careful about special characters:

*Edited by Shnugo: Added missing closing `)` after `.value()`...*

```
SELECT id, displayname = 
       STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + displayname
              FROM #t b 
              WHERE b.id = a.id 
              FOR XML PATH, TYPE
             ).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')
FROM #t a
GROUP BY id;
```

You can then add tags such as `<br>` safely wherever you want them.

Comment: It is very important to point to `.value()` and the implicit escaping mechanism. But if the input data contains special characters (like an `<`) this could lead ot invalid HTML. See my answer... btw: There's a missing closing `)` before `,1,1,'')`

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
SELECT id, displayname = 
    REPLACE(
        STUFF(
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT '§§§§§' + displayname 
                FROM #t b 
                WHERE b.id = a.id 
                FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 5,  ''
        ), '§§§§§', '<br/>'
    )
FROM #t a
GROUP BY id
```

This assumes that none of your `dislayname`s contains character sequence `'§§§§§'`.

Just in case: if you are running SQL Server 2017, you can use `STRING_AGG()`, the newly (finally!) added string aggregation function:

```
SELECT id, STRING_AGG(displayname, '<br/>') displayname
FROM #t a
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: The first is unfortunately not sophisticated enough -- `<` and `>` will be escaped. You can explicitly replace them back, but then strings that actually contained those escaped values will suffer... The simplest workaround is to use some value that's "surely never in the input" and then replace that afterwards. I think there are duplicates on SO that demonstrate string concat with this technique and/or `text()`, but I'm too lazy to search for them right now.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: yes I see your point. I updated my answer... Thanks.

Comment: This works and is a great approach in simple cases, but: It is very dangerous to mix XML and string, due to the implicit escaping mechanisms. I'd suggest to build the whole thing within the XML universe as XHTML (see my answer). +1 from my side anyway...

Answer (score 2):

To add to Gordon's important remark:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(id INT, displayname VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(1,'value 1.1'),(1,'value 1.2')
                      ,(2,'value 2.1'),(2,'value 2.2.'),(2,'value 2.3 with special characters $<>')
                      ,(3,'value 3.1');
```

--the query

```
SELECT id, displayname = 
       STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT '<br/>, ' + displayname
              FROM @tbl b 
              WHERE b.id = a.id 
              FOR XML PATH, TYPE
             ).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 7, '')
FROM @tbl a
GROUP BY id;
```

It is important to know, that any text **within** XML must be escaped properly. Including special characters is no problem, but you must use `TYPE` and  `.value()` to read from the XML with implicit re-escaping.

The result (look at the second line carefully!):

```
value 1.1<br/>, value 1.2
value 2.1<br/>, value 2.2.<br/>, value 2.3 with special characters $<>
value 3.1
```

The problem now is: This might create broken HTML...

### My suggestion: stick to XHTML and try to avoid any string-based coding

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(id INT, displayname VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(1,'value 1.1'),(1,'value 1.2')
                      ,(2,'value 2.1'),(2,'value 2.2.'),(2,'value 2.3 with special characters $<>')
                      ,(3,'value 3.1');

SELECT id
     , displayname = (SELECT displayname AS [*]
                      FROM @tbl b 
                      WHERE b.id = a.id 
                      FOR XML PATH('line'),TYPE).query('for $l in /line
                                                        return
                                                        ($l/text(),<br/>)
                                                       ')
FROM @tbl a
GROUP BY id;
```

The result is XML typed and can be placed within other XHTML without thinking about the escaped entities:

```
value 1.1<br />value 1.2<br />
value 2.1<br />value 2.2.<br />value 2.3 with special characters $&lt;&gt;<br />
value 3.1<br />
```

## Hint: GMB's answer will work too

In GMB's answer the `TYPE` with `.value()` is not used (as it was recommended in *normal* cases). You can use this approach safely if dealing with strings. But keep in mind, that it is very dangerous to **mix** XML and string approaches, due to the implicit escaping...

Comment: A comprehensive answer, that SO could use more of... +1!